# Reset or Reload a JPanel contents in Card Layout depending on the selections in other panels

Tags: swing, jpanel, wizard, cardlayout

I'm using a card layout for creating a series of panels.

I created a JFrame class. And to the instance of this frame class, obtained contentPane and set CardLayout. Added all the panels to this contentPane.

```
public class JFrameClass1234 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public static JFrameClass1234 jFrameInstance1234;
public static JPanelFirstScreen jPanelFirstScreen;
public static JPanelSecondScreen jPanelSecondScreen;
public static JPanelThirdScreen jPanelThirdScreen;
public static JPanelFourthScreen jPanelFourthScreen;
public static JPanelFifthScreen jPanelFifthScreen;

public static void main(String args[]) {

java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

           jFrameInstance1234 = new JFrameClass1234();

           jPanelFirstScreen = new JPanelFirstScreen();
           jPanelSecondScreen = new JPanelSecondScreen();
           jPanelThirdScreen = new JPanelThirdScreen();
           jPanelFourthScreen = new JPanelFourthScreen();
           jPanelFifthScreen = new JPanelFifthScreen();

           final Container pane = jFrameInstance1234.getContentPane();
           pane.add(jPanelFirstScreen,card1);
           pane.add(jPanelSecondScreen,card2);
           pane.add(jPanelThirdScreen,card3);
           pane.add(jPanelFourthScreen,card4);
           pane.add(jPanelFifthScreen,card5);
           CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(pane.getLayout());
           cl.show(pane, card1);
           jFrameInstance1234.setVisible(true);
           }
      });
  } 

}//end of class
```

Now, I'm able to move between panels by calling the following methods inside the "Next" or "Back" button action listners of each panel:

```
//For going back to previous panel
private void gotoPreviousPanel() {
final Container pane = JFrameClass1234.jFrameInstance1234.getContentPane();
CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (pane.getLayout());
cl.show(pane, JFrameClass1234.card1);
JFrameClass1234.JFrameinstance1234.setVisible(true);
}

//For going to next panel
private void gotoNextPanel() {
    final Container pane = JFrameClass1234.jFrameInstance1234
            .getContentPane();
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (pane.getLayout());
    cl.show(pane, JFrameClass1234.card3);
    JFrameClass1234.jFrameInstance1234.setVisible(true);
}
```

But when I move between panels, the values are retaining (Not getting reset or reload). I want to reset or reload the panels when I move back and fro between panels.
Or say a "textbox" in second panel should always be reloaded when shown, depending on the "ComboBox" option selected in the first panel. CAN SOMEBODY HELP me for achieving this???

What must be ideal design(logic) I must follow for such situations? Is there any documentations specific to my situation? Is the way I'm following using card layout is correct? else recommend me correct design.

Thanks,
Chandra

Answer (score 0):

You can declare one **Singleton** class with properties (from different UI panels you have). Also, declare an **interface** with a method updateUIFields() and have all the panels implement this interface. Update the singleton object as you update fields in one panel(currently displayed panel). Before switching to a different panel in the card, reload or reset based on the selection/values you have stored in the singleton object. Implement this logic in the interface method. Reset the values in the Singleton object if required.

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding  the ancestorListener() to the JPanel compoenent being refreshed.